# SQL Loader : Multibyte character error

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to load a file with few records containing multibyte(special) character using SQL Loader into Oracle table via a control file. But it is giving me Multibyte character error if I use the below control file.

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET UTF8
INTO TABLE MY_DB.T1
(
MESSAGE BOUNDFILLER POSITION(437:515) CHAR,
FILLER ":MESSAGE",
MY_DTE DATE "DDMMYYYYHH24MISS" "CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN NULL ELSE NULL END",
XTRA_TXT POSITION(516:755) CHAR
)
```

The special character is at the position 530.

In other case when I place the FILLER field at the end of control file after MY_DTE field without any other changes the records are loaded successfully.

Also, if I keep the control file as is and add any character before the special character position (530), then also records are successfully loaded.

I am not sure what really is causing the issue. PS- The type of field FILLER in the table is `VARCHAR2(79 BYTE)`.

Comment: What is the actual error message you get? Also what is the DB character set, and how many chars and how many bytes are actually in positions 516:755?

Comment: In the logs I can find the error as : RECORD 616 : Rejected - Error on table My_DB.T1, column MY_DTE.

Comment: Also ,the NLS_CHARACTERSET in the table NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS is UTF8 and NLS_LANGUAGE is AMERICAN

Comment: @AlexPoole The characters starting from 516 looks like : REBATE JAN 17 â DEC 17        .....rest spaces till 755th character

Comment: Are you working on Windows or Linux? I assume the file is actually saved as UTF-8?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am working on LINUX. This issue occurred in PROD environment and I got file transferred to my local environment on LINUX.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it working make following before you use sqlloader:

- Set your LOCALE to `UTF-8` (in Windows it would be `chcp 65001`)
- Set your `NLS_LANG` environment variable to UTF-8, e.g. `set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8`
- Declare `CHARACTERSET UTF8` in your sqlloader file.

Then it should work.

Comment: As suggested I exported the variables LOCALE and NLS_LANG but still facing the same error

Comment: Are you sure your file is saved as UTF-8?

Comment: Yes..if I am shifting the special character by one position right, it is getting loaded into the table as '-'..Its working even I remove the FILLER field from the .CTL file without modifying the data

Comment: Why does shifting a character proves that the file is UTF-8? Can you share one line of your data?

Comment: I was just adding one thing that I tried...some part of the text where the special char is -REBATE JAN 17 â DEC 17 .....rest spaces till the end. The special character when loaded into table can be viewed as '-'

Comment: I cannot share the data as it is quite confidential..but for your reference the HEX code for the special character is e2...I will try if I could pull up some masked data or a screenshot

Comment: Then your file seems to be **NOT** UTF-8 - in this case the hex value should be `C3 A2` for `â`

Comment: But the ASCII table lookup at www.tutorialspoint.com says the E2 is the hexcode for Latin small letter a with circumflex i.e. â. Though HEX UTF-8 byte is C3 A2 for this character, does it means file is not UTF-8??

Comment: I don't know, that's the reason why I asked you for the hex values of your data.

Comment: I did : file -i <filename> it gave the character set as us-ascii.. Then I tried to convert the file to UTF-8 using the command : iconv -f us-ascii -t UTF-8 <filename> -o <outputfile>. It gives an error - iconv: illegal input sequence at position <some position>

Comment: You cannot have `â` in ASCII - which is 7-bit only. That's why you get an error. As UTF-8 is a strict super-set of ASCII, an ASCII file is binary exactly the same as the UTF-8 version.